# How to call a pre configured postgres function when using jdbc?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to call a pre configured function using java code.
This is the code i am using:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + ip + ":5432/" + db,
                            username, password);
c.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt = c.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT public.myFunc ("1","2","3"));

stmt.close();
c.close();
```

The function itself has some validation and in the end an INSERT command.
When I run the query from pgAdmin, I can see that the row is added, but when I run the same query as written above, nothing happens.

Also tried replacing the executeQuery with execute and executeUpdate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the documentation about the right way of [Calling Stored Functions](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/callproc.html), in your case you can use :

```
CallableStatement callStmt = c.prepareCall("{call myFunc(?, ?, ?)}");
callStmt.setString(1, "1");
callStmt.setString(2, "2");
callStmt.setString(3, "3");
callStmt.execute();
callStmt.close();
```

---

**Important about your code**

- If you mean to use Integer `1` instead of String `"1"` you have to change `callStmt.setString` to `callStmt.setInt`
- The default schema of postgres is public so you don't need to mention it, you can mention it if you use another schema
- The quote in Java `"` should be escaped by `\"`
- Don't concatenate attributes with your query, this can cause Syntax error and SQL Injection

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I have applied your solution but the result is the same, I run the query successfully but the change is not reflected in the DB.

Comment: Did you try it with setAutoCommit or without it, it seems you dont commit your statement

Comment: THANKS!! that was the issue